# Unsuccessful attempts at implementing concurrency

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm having difficulty getting go concurrency to work correctly. I'm working with data loaded from an XML Data Source. Once I load the data into memory, i  loop through the XML elements and perform an operation. The code prior to the concurrency addition has been tested and functional, and I don't believe it has any influence on the concurrency addition. I have 2 failed attempts at concurrency implementations, both with different outputs. I used locking because i dont want to enter a race condition.

For this implementation, it never enters the goroutine.

```
    var mu sync.Mutex

    // length is 197K
    for i:=0;i<len(listings.Listings);i++{
      go func(){
         mu.Lock()

         // code execution (tested prior to adding concurrency and locking)

         mu.Unlock()     
      }()
    }
```

For this implementation using waitGroups, `a runtime out of memory occurs`

```
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // length is 197K
    for i:=0;i<len(listings.Listings);i++{
       wg.Add(1)
       go func(){
           mu.Lock()

           // code execution (tested prior to adding concurrency and locking and wait group)      

           wg.Done()
           mu.Unlock()   
       }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

I'm not really sure what's going on and could use some assistance.

Comment: Since you run this in a Mutex there is no concurrency going on, what’s the idea behind it? Anyway it is probably better to reuse the function definition and only start a limited number of goroutines in parallel. (Or none at all if you keep the mutex)

Comment: Also, if you're using `i` within the goroutine function, the value won't be what you expect, since all the goroutines are seeing the value of `i` at the time that the code executes,  which is not necessarily the value as of the time the goroutine was created. You can solve that problem by putting `i := i` right after the `for` so that each goroutine is using a different variable.

Comment: @AndySchweig i remmed the mutex since it doesnt hold any value since we arent changing the state of any data. thanks for the assistance with the i := i any other possible issues?

Comment: You may want to think about whether you really want to have 197k goroutines running at the same time. If the code is CPU bound, you're not going to get any benefit from allowing more goroutines than the number of CPUs to run in parallel, and that might actually slow things down. If the code is doing a lot of waiting, it makes sense to have more copies executing at the same time, but you still might not want to have so many of them running at once.

Comment: @AndySchweig i was under the impression golang would be managing the running goroutines based on the cpu threads available. how do i modify this so it only executes the available threads?

Comment: Yes, the runtime manages the goroutines, but they're not free. You have to gauge what the overhead of the goroutines is compared to the possible efficiency gains of making the code concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need `Mutex` here if you want to make it concurrent
2. 197K goroitines are a lot, try lower amount of goroutines. You can accomplish it by creating N goroutines, when each of them is listening to the same channel.

https://play.golang.org/p/s4e0YyHdyPq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Listing struct{}

func main() {
    var (
        wg          sync.WaitGroup
        concurrency = 100
    )

    c := make(chan Listing)

    wg.Add(concurrency)
    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
        go func(ci <-chan Listing) {
            for l := range ci {
                // code, l is a single Listing
                fmt.Printf("%v", l)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(c)
    }

    // replace with your var
    listings := []Listing{Listing{}}
    for _, l := range listings {
        c <- l
    }

    close(c)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea whats going on here. Im real new to concurrency with go and dont quite understand channels

Comment: @jkushner basically this code spins up fixed amount of goroutines (can be changed), each goroutine will work as receiver. Also there is one sender, which iterates over the listings and sends message to the channel to be picked up by the goroutines.